# Upper bound and monotony

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I'm trying to figure out wether I understand the meaning of the following sequence 
correctly. Let $\displaystyle a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k+n}, n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Is this a correct upper bound?

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k+n} < \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n} = n \cdot\frac{1}{n} = 1.$$

Is there a way to proof the monotony?

Comment: [A duplicate?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/73550/11619) $$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac1{2n+2}+\frac1{2n+1}-\frac1{n+1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since for all $n\in\mathbb N$
\begin{align*}a_{n+1}-a_n&=\frac 1{2n+2}+\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac 1{n+k+1}-\frac 1{n+k}\right)\\
&=\frac 1{2n+2}+\frac 1{2n+1}-\frac 1{n+1}\\
&=\frac 1{2n+1}-\frac 1{2n+2}\geq 0,
\end{align*}
the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is strictly increasing.