# Prove by induction: $\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...\frac{1}{2n}\right)^2<\frac{1}{2},n\ge 1$

Tags: inequality, induction, harmonic-numbers

Prove by induction: $\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...\frac{1}{2n}\right)^2<\frac{1}{2},n\ge 1$

For $n=1$ inequality holds.

For $n=k$

$$\left(\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k+2}+...\frac{1}{2k}\right)^2<\frac{1}{2}$$

For $n=k+1$

$$\left(\frac{1}{k+2}+\frac{1}{k+3}+...\frac{1}{2k+2}\right)^2<\frac{1}{2}$$

I don't know how to prove this.

Is it better to use direct method or contradiction?

Comment: This post seems - to some extent - related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207675/prove-frac1-n1-frac1-n2-cdots-frac12n-frac2536-by-mathe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I  have Cauchy-Schwarz inequality prove your inequality

we have
\begin{align*}\dfrac{1}{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n+n}&\le\sqrt{n\left(\dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\dfrac{1}{(n+2)^2}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{(n+n)^2}\right)}\\
&<\sqrt{n\left(\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}+\dfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{(n+n-1)(n+n)}\right)}\\
&=\sqrt{n\left(\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{2n}\right)}\\
&=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{align*}

**EDIT** If you must use induction, I think you must induction this following Stronger inequality
$$\dfrac{1}{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n+n}\le\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\dfrac{1}{4n+1}$$

because we only prove this
$$\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\dfrac{1}{4n+1}-\dfrac{1}{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{2n+1}+\dfrac{1}{2n+2}<\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\dfrac{1}{4n+5}$$
we only prove
$$\dfrac{1}{4n+5}+\dfrac{1}{2n+1}<\dfrac{1}{2n+2}+\dfrac{1}{4n+1}$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow (4n+5)(2n+1)(4n+1)+(4n+5)(2n+1)(2n+2)-(4n+5)(2n+2)(4n+1)-(2n+1)(2n+2)(4n+1)>0$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow 3>0$$
It it clear

Answer (score 1):

$$ a_n = H_{2n}-H_{n} = \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2n} $$
is an increasing sequence, since:
$$ a_{n+1}-a_n = \frac{1}{2n+2}+\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}>0$$
hence:
$$ \forall n\geq 1,\qquad a_n \leq \lim_{n\to +\infty}a_n = \log(2) $$
and the problem boils down just to showing that $\log^2(2)<\frac{1}{2}$.

That follows from:
$$\log(2) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x}< \sqrt{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(1+x)^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$$