# Showing that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}-\ln(n)=0.5772\ldots$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers, euler-mascheroni-constant

How to show that  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}-\ln(n)\right]=0.5772\ldots$$

No clue at all. Need help!  Appreciated!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant

Comment: I give one of the shorter proofs here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306371/simple-proof-of-showing-the-harmonic-number-h-n-theta-log-n/306379#306379

Comment: You mean $\color{Red}{=} \gamma \color{Red}{\approx} 0.5772$. Most often this is the *definition* of the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$ - so were you looking to show the limit exists or do you have a different definition of the constant?

Comment: @computer.nerd: I am not putting my answer here to choose it. There is nothing wrong with it and it was upvoted. Now, some people insist on downvoting and I do not why. It is a short slick proof to the problem. I am posting it here again We will use the following facts

1) $$ \psi(k+1)-\psi(k)=\frac{1}{k} \implies \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}=\psi(n+1)+\gamma,\quad \psi(1)=-\gamma .$$

2) $$ \psi(x) = \ln(x) - \frac{1}{2x} - O\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right).  $$

Now, 

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}-\ln(n)= \lim_{n\to \infty} \psi(n+1)+\gamma-\ln(n) = \gamma = 0.5772. $$

Comment: see also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2869141/442

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Showing that
$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k-\log(n)\right)$
exists**

Note that
$$
\frac1{n+1}\le\int_n^{n+1}\frac1x\,\mathrm{d}x\le\frac1n\tag{1}
$$
Summing the right hand inequality shows that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k-\log(n+1)\tag{2}
$$
is increasing. Summing the left hand inequality shows that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k-\log(n)\tag{3}
$$
is decreasing.

Since $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)=0$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ show that $\displaystyle\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k-\log(n)\right)$ exists and is between $0$ and $1$.

---

**Evaluating $\gamma$**

Define the Harmonic Numbers
$$
H(n)=1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\dots+\frac1n\tag{4}
$$
and the Alternating Harmonic Numbers
$$
AH(n)=1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\dots+(-1)^{n-1}\frac1n\tag{5}
$$
and the Alternating Harmonic Tails
$$
AHT(n)=\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{n+2}+\frac1{n+3}-\frac1{n+4}+\dots\tag{6}
$$
Remember that
$$
\begin{align}
\log(2)&=1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\frac15-\frac16+\dots\\
&=AH(n)+(-1)^nAHT(n)\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Notice that for $n\gt0$,
$$
\begin{align}
&H(2^n)-H(2^{n-1})\\
&=\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\dots+\frac1{2^n}\right)-\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\dots+\frac1{2^{n-1}}\right)\\
&=\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\dots+\frac1{2^n}\right)-\left(\frac22+\frac24+\frac26+\frac28+\dots+\frac2{2^n}\right)\\
&=\left(1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\dots-\frac1{2^n}\right)\\
&=AH(2^n)\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
H(2^n)
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^n\left(H(2^k)-H(2^{k-1})\right)\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^nAH(2^k)\tag{9}
\end{align}
$$
Because $\displaystyle\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(H(2^n)-\log(2^n)\Big)$, subtract $n\log(2)$ from $(9)$ and rearrange terms to get
$$
H(2^n)-\log(2^n)
=1+\sum_{k=1}^n\left(AH(2^k)-\log(2)\right)\tag{10}
$$
For $k\gt0$, $2^k$ is even, so we have from $(7)$
$$
\log(2)-AH(2^k)=AHT(2^k)\tag{11}
$$
Using $(10)$ and $(11)$, we get
$$
\gamma=1-\sum_{k=1}^\infty AHT(2^k)\tag{12}
$$
Expedite the computation of $(12)$ using the following integral,
$$
\begin{align}
AHT(m)
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{m+j}\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{x^m}{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac1{j\binom{m+j}{j}2^j}\tag{13}
\end{align}
$$
where the last sum in $(13)$ is gotten by repeatedly integrating by parts. It converges far more quickly than the alternating harmonic tail, two lines above.

Using $(12)$ and $(13)$, it is not unreasonable to compute
$$
\gamma=0.57721566490153286060651209\tag{14}
$$
In fact, I used $(12)$ and $(13)$ to compute [$10000$ digits of $\gamma$](http://www.whim.org/nebula/math/gamma10k.html).

---

**A Slightly Different Sum**

Since $AHT(2^k-1)=2^{-k}-AHT(2^k)$, we can rewrite $(12)$ as
$$
\gamma=\sum_{k=1}^\infty AHT(2^k-1)\tag{15}
$$
and use $(13)$ and $(15)$ to get $(14)$, as well.

---

**A Mathematica Implementation**

Here is an implementation of the algorithm above to compute $d$ digits of $\gamma$.

`AHT[m_,d_]:=Module[{p=10^(d+2), j=1, b=1, t, s=SetPrecision[1,d+4]-1}, 
  While[b=b*2(m+j)/j; (t=j b)<=p, s=s+1/t; j=j+1]; SetPrecision[s,d]]`

`EulerG[d_]:=Module[{n=Ceiling[10d/3]}, Sum[AHT[2^k-1,d], {k,1,n}]]`

Answer (score 16):

**Abel's partial summation technique**:

Let $A(n) = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n a(k)$. We then have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{N} a(n) f(n) & = \sum_{n=1}^{N} f(n) (A(n)- A(n-1)) = \sum_{n=1}^{N} A(n) f(n) - \sum_{n=1}^{N} A(n-1) f(n)\\
& = \sum_{n=1}^{N} A(n)f(n) - \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} A(n) f(n+1)\\
& = A(N)f(N) - A(0) f(1) - \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} A(n) (f(n+1)-f(n))
\end{align*}
(The above is nothing but the discrete version of integration by parts).

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N} a(n) f(n) = \int_{1^-}^{N^+} f(t) d(A(t)) =  f(t) A(t) \rvert_{1^-}^{N^+} - \int_{1^-}^{N^+} A(t) f'(t) dt$$ (The second integral can be interpreted as a Riemann-Stieltjes integral.)

---

Now to the main proof. Consider the sum $\displaystyle \sum_{n \leq N} \frac1n$. Choose $a(n) = 1$ and $f(n) = \frac1n$. Note that we have $A(t) = \lfloor t \rfloor = t - \{t\}$. Hence, we get that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \leq N} \frac1n & = \left. \frac{t-\{t\}}t \right \rvert_{1^-}^{N^+} + \int_{1^-}^{N^+} \frac{(t-\{t\})}{t^2} dt\\
& = 1 + \int_{1^-}^{N^+} \frac{dt}t - \int_{1^-}^{N^+} \frac{\{t\}}{t^2} dt\\
& = 1 + \log (N) - \int_{1^-}^{\infty} \frac{\{t\}}{t^2} dt + \int_{N^+}^{\infty} \frac{\{t\}}{t^2} dt\\
& = \left(1 - \int_{1^-}^{\infty} \frac{\{t\}}{t^2} dt \right) + \log(N) + \int_{N^+}^{\infty} \frac{\{t\}}{t^2} dt
\end{align*}
Note that $\displaystyle \int_{N^+}^{\infty} \frac{\{t\}}{t^2} dt \leq \int_{N^+}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t^2} dt = \frac1N$.

Also note that by the same argument, we also have that $\displaystyle 0 < \int_{1^-}^{\infty} \frac{\{t\}}{t^2} dt < 1$ and hence $\displaystyle 0 < \left(1 - \int_{1^-}^{\infty} \frac{\{t\}}{t^2} dt \right) < 1$. Denoting $\displaystyle \left(1 - \int_{1^-}^{\infty} \frac{\{t\}}{t^2} dt \right) = \gamma$, we get the following result.
$$\sum_{n \leq N} \frac1n = \gamma + \log(N) + \mathcal{O} \left(\frac1N \right)$$
$\gamma \approx 0.5772\ldots$ and is called the Euler-Mascheroni constant. Hence, we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\sum_{k = 1}^n \dfrac1k - \log(n) \right) = \displaystyle \left(1 - \int_{1^-}^{\infty} \frac{\{t\}}{t^2} dt \right) = \gamma \approx 0.5772$$

---

We can easily see that $\gamma$ must be greater than $\dfrac12$ from the figure below. $\gamma$ is the area between the blue curve, which is $\displaystyle \dfrac1{\lfloor x \rfloor}$ and the red curve, which is $\dfrac1x$. The curve $\dfrac1x$ between $(n,n+1)$ lies below the line segment joining $\left(n,\dfrac1n \right)$ and $\left(n+1, \dfrac1{n+1} \right)$. Hence, \begin{align}
\gamma & = \text{Area between the blue and red curve}\\
& \geq \text{Area between the blue curve and the curve formed by the line segments }\\
& \text{joining $\left(n,\dfrac1n \right)$ and $\left(n+1, \dfrac1{n+1} \right)$}\\
& = \dfrac12 \times 1 \times \left(1-\dfrac12 \right) + \dfrac12 \times 1 \times \left(\dfrac12 - \dfrac13\right) + \dfrac12 \times 1 \times \left(\dfrac13 - \dfrac14\right) + \cdots\\
& = \dfrac12 \left(1 - \dfrac12 + \dfrac12 - \dfrac13 + \dfrac13 - \dfrac14 \pm\right) = \dfrac12 = 0.5
\end{align}

[image]