# Prove that $\{x_n\}_n$ is convergent.

Tags: convergence-divergence

Here is an exercise:

> Let $x_n=1+2+\dots+\frac1n-\ln n$. Prove that $\{x_n\}_n$ is convergent.

(I believe that this can be found in the site, however I cannot find immediately, so I post it here.)

The hints are much appreciated. I don't want complete proof.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This was proven in the site quite some times. Do you know about $\gamma$; Euler's constant?

Comment: [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412406/need-to-show-that-lim-x-to-infty-left-sum-n-le-x-frac1n-ln-x-rig/412415#412415)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. But I've heard it.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: thanks for the link.+1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's present a different proof than any I've seen on this site, via a picture and a hint.

Look carefully at the following and remember that $\displaystyle \int_1^x \frac 1t dt = \ln x$:

[image]

Justify that the area in blue is the limit you're looking for, and for that matter the first $n$ blue bits corresponds to the $n$th term of the sequence. Show the limit exists and is finite (which can be done entirely with the picture too).

Comment: Wow! A good job. Very appreciated! +10)