# Why does $\sum_{k=2}^\infty k \left( \sum_{j=2^k}^{2^{k+1}-1} \frac{(-1)^j}{j} \right )+{1\over2}-{1\over3} = \gamma$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

How could one prove that

$$x = \sum_{k=2}^\infty k \left( \sum_{j=2^k}^{2^{k+1}-1} \frac{(-1)^j}{j} \right )$$
is such that $x+{1\over2}-{1\over3} = \gamma$ ?

I am having problems just calculating to see if it is correct, let alone proving it...

Comment: In that case, where did you get this?

Comment: @WillJagy: To what case does "that" refer to?

Comment: You do not know whether this is correct, nor can you calculate it. Yet you have a suspicion that it is correct. Someone or something told you it was true, or at least likely and worth investigating. You have not identified the someone or something.

Comment: @WillJagy: It is a conjecture, which I want to prove, based on an interpretation of the Ramanujan expansion. I can show that it's close, by the means of calculating it, but I have no proof for it.

Comment: Why don't you write the sum on the left and $\gamma -\frac{1}{6}$ on the right?

Comment: @JohnBentin: You say təˈmeɪtoʊz, I say təˈmɑːtoʊz... Let's Call the Whole Thing Off...

Comment: I would love to see this proven in a way other than proof by exhaustion.

Comment: @JohnBentin: the $\frac12-\frac13$ is just the $k=1$ term. My question is why not simply extend the sum to $k=1$ and eliminate the $\frac12-\frac13$?

Comment: @robjohn: That would help in answering the question; Please share.

Comment: @JohnWO: I don't understand what you want me to share. I've answered the question. I was simply wondering why the $k=1$ term was brought out of the outer sum as $\frac12-\frac13$.

Comment: @robjohn: Yes, that's simplest.

Answer (score 3):

Start with equation $(15)$ in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/344574):
$$
\begin{align}
\gamma
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty AHT(2^k-1)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^j}{2^k+j}\\
&=\color{#C00000}{\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{j=2^k}^\infty\frac{(-1)^j}j}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{i=k}^\infty\sum_{j=2^i}^{2^{i+1}-1}\frac{(-1)^j}j\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^i\sum_{j=2^i}^{2^{i+1}-1}\frac{(-1)^j}j\\
&=\color{#C00000}{\sum_{i=1}^\infty i\sum_{j=2^i}^{2^{i+1}-1}\frac{(-1)^j}j}\\
&=\frac12-\frac13+\sum_{i=2}^\infty i\sum_{j=2^i}^{2^{i+1}-1}\frac{(-1)^j}j
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?