# Simple proof Euler–Mascheroni $\gamma$ constant

Tags: limits, logarithms, euler-mascheroni-constant, harmonic-numbers

I'm searching for a really simple and beautiful proof that the sequence $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} = \sum\nolimits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} - \log(n)$ converges.
At first I want to know if my answer is OK.

**My try:**
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} - \log (n)\right) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} [\log(k)-\log(k+1)]\right)$

$ = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n} + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} \left[\log(\frac{k}{k+1})+\frac{1}{k}\right]\right) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[\frac{1}{k}-\log(\frac{k+1}{k})\right]$
*Now we prove that the last sum converges by the comparison test:*
$\frac{1}{k}-\log(\frac{k+1}{k}) < \frac{1}{k^2} \Leftrightarrow k<k^2\log(\frac{k+1}{k})+1$
which surely holds for $k\geqslant 1$

---

As $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}$ converges $ \Rightarrow \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[\frac{1}{k}-\log(\frac{k+1}{k})\right]$ converges and we name this limit $\gamma$
q.e.d

Comment: Hint: look at the function $y=1/x$ compared to "step functions" above and below that curve, and look at what happens when you integrate.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306371/simple-proof-of-showing-the-harmonic-number-h-n-theta-log-n/306379#306379

Comment: the diagrams are not very good, but you can [get the idea here](http://www.macalester.edu/aratra/chapt2/chapt2_4a.html).

Comment: @OldJohn, I do not believe that posting nude photos of your first wife is an appropriate use of this site.

Comment: @OldJohn, I see, actually a link to a Macalester College discussion of the harmonic series. Natural mistake.

Comment: @OldJohn Amazing link thanks a lot !

Comment: @WillJagy You have clearly never met my ex-wife, if you believe that she would ever fit into a sentence containing the word "harmonic" ...

Comment: @OldJohn, true, never met her. There is a running joke on a TV series called NCIS, in which FBI agent Fornell married a woman whom NCIS agent Gibbs had divorced. At one point Fornell says "In my defense, I didn't believe him."

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344314/showing-that-lim-n-to-infty-sumn-k-1-frac1k-lnn-0-5772-ldots) is closely related.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

One elegant way to show that the sequence converges is to show that it's both decreasing and bounded below.

It's decreasing because $u_n-u_{n-1} = \frac1n - \log n + \log(n-1) = \frac1n + \log(1-\frac1n) < 0$ for all $n$. (The inequality is valid because $\log(1-x)$ is a concave function, hence lies beneath the line $-x$ that is tangent to its graph at $0$; plugging in $x=\frac1n$ yields $\log(1-\frac1n) \le -\frac1n$.)

It's bounded below because
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n \frac1j > \int_1^{n+1} \frac{dt}t = \log (n+1) > \log n,
$$
and so $u_n>0$ for all $n$. (The inequality is valid because the sum is a left-hand endpoint Riemann sum for the integral, and the function $\frac1t$ is decreasing.)

Answer (score 10):

**Upper Bound**

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1n-\log\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)
&=\int_0^{1/n}\frac{t\,\mathrm{d}t}{1+t}\\
&\le\int_0^{1/n}t\,\mathrm{d}t\\[3pt]
&=\frac1{2n^2}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\gamma
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1n-\log\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)\right)\\
&\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2n^2}\\
&\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2n^2-\frac12}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac12\left(\frac1{n-\frac12}-\frac1{n+\frac12}\right)\\[9pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$

---

**Lower Bound**

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1n-\log\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)
&=\int_0^{1/n}\frac{t\,\mathrm{d}t}{1+t}\\
&\ge\int_0^{1/n}\frac{t}{1+\frac1n}\,\mathrm{d}t\\[3pt]
&=\frac1{2n(n+1)}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\gamma
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1n-\log\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)\right)\\
&\ge\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2n(n+1)}\\[3pt]
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac12\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)\\[6pt]
&=\frac12
\end{align}
$$

---

**A Better Upper Bound**

Using [Jensen's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) on the concave $\frac{t}{1+t}$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1n-\log\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)
&=\frac1n\left(n\int_0^{1/n}\frac{t\,\mathrm{d}t}{1+t}\right)\\
&\le\frac1n\frac{n\int_0^{1/n}t\,\mathrm{d}t}{1+n\int_0^{1/n}t\,\mathrm{d}t}\\
&=\frac1{n(2n+1)}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, since the sum of the [Alternating Harmonic Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Alternating_harmonic_series) is $\log(2)$,
$$
\begin{align}
\gamma
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1n-\log\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)\right)\\
&\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n(2n+1)}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty2\left(\frac1{2n}-\frac1{2n+1}\right)\\[6pt]
&=2(1-\log(2))
\end{align}
$$

Comment: can you copy the last part of your answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2513477/help-me-prove-lim-n→∞-left-sum-k-1n-frac1k-log-n-right-1-2) ?

Comment: @robjohn may I know how do you get the inequality $$n\ \int_{0}^{\frac {1} {n}} \dfrac {t\ \mathrm {d} t} {1 + t} \leq \dfrac {n\ \int_{0}^{\frac {1} {n}} t\ \mathrm {d} t} {1 + n\ \int_{0}^{\frac {1} {n}} t\ \mathrm {d}t}\ ?$$ Is it the consequence of Jensen's inequality? Thanks.

Comment: It is Jensen with the concave function $\varphi(t)=\frac{t}{1+t}$ and then $n\int_0^{\frac1n}\varphi(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\le\varphi\left(n\int_0^{\frac1n}t\,\mathrm{d}t\right)$.

Comment: Since $\varphi$ is concave on $[0,\infty)$ it follows that for any $x,y \geq 0$ we have $\varphi (tx + (1-t)y) \geq t\ \varphi (x) + (1-t)\ \varphi (y),$ for all $t \in [0,1].$ Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is one of the characterizations of a concave function. It is also true that $\varphi''(x)\le0$ on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Very elegant proof of the bounds of Euler-Mascheroni's constant. +1

Comment: @robjohn A bounded sequence is not always convergent

Comment: @AmbicaGovind: I don't quite understand your objection. The sum is a sum of positive terms. As long as the partial sums are bounded above (they are bounded above by $1$), the sum converges.

Comment: @robjohn Should it not be monotonically increasing then, in addition to being bounded above? This is the theorem I've always used. Well yes, intuitively being bounded above should be enough, but the theorem?

Comment: @AmbicaGovind: The sequence of partial sums is increasing since the sum consists of positive terms.

Answer (score 4):

All we use here is the power series expansion for $\log(1+z)$ with $|z|<1$:

$$
\log(1+z)=z-{z^2\over2}+{z^3\over3}-{z^4\over4}+\cdots\tag1
$$

It suffices to note that

$$
\log N=\log{N+1\over1}+\mathcal O\left(\frac1N\right)=\sum_{n\le N}\log{n+1\over n}+\mathcal O\left(\frac1N\right)
$$

Thus, we have

$$
\sum_{n\le N}\frac1n-\log N=\sum_{n\le N}\left\{\frac1n-\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)\right\}+\mathcal O\left(\frac1N\right)\tag2
$$

As $n\to+\infty$, we know from (1) that

$$
\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)=\frac1n+\mathcal O\left(1\over n^2\right)
$$

This is sufficient for us to show that the partial sum on the right hand side of (2) will converge when $N\to+\infty$. Thus, we know the left hand side of (2) converges too.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof which is slightly ore elementary than the ones above.

Consider the following well-known inequality
$$\frac1{n+1}<\log (n+1)-\log n<\frac1n\tag{$*$}$$
(it can be easily proves that using that $f_n=(1+1/n)^{n+1}$ and $e_n=(1+1/n)^n$ are decreasing and increasing, respectively, and both converge towards $e$)

First, by $(1)$ it follows that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k>\sum_{k=1}^n (\log(k+1)-\log k)=\log(n+1)>\log n,$$
so $u_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k - \log n$ is bounded below by $0$.
But on the other hand by $(1)$ it also follows that
$$u_{n+1}-u_n =\frac1{n+1}-\log (n+1)+\log n<0,$$
so the sequence is strictly decreasing. Hence by the Monotone convergence theorem $(u_n)_n$ is convergent, so we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is nice. A simple proof by using graph:

By using Rieamann sums of $y=\frac1x$:
$$\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1k<\ln(n)<\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1k$$
$$-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1k<-\ln(n)<-\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac1k$$
$$\frac1n<u_n<1.$$
So, $(u_n)$ is bounded. On the other hand,
$$u_{n}-u_{n+1}=\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)-\frac1{n+1}=\int_n^{n+1}\frac1x dx-\frac1{n+1}>\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{n+1}=0.$$
So, $(u_n)$ is a bounded decreasing sequence. We are done.

Answer (score -2):

You can also prove it by drawing the curve of 1/x and then you can draw some rectangles (with lines on $x=1,2,...,n$)  and shade them (which will be little above the curve) and find the area of the shaded rectangles that will be the sum $1+1/2+/1/3+...+1/n$ and find the area underneath the curve which will be greater than the area of the shaded rectangles. That way you can prove that the sequence is bounded below. Further to find if it is decreasing or increasing, you can find the value of $s_{n+1}-s{n}$ with the help of same method and it will be lower than 0 so you can conclude that it is decreasing. After that you can easily prove that it is converging to Euler's constant which is $1+1/2+1/3+....+1/n-logn$.

(not an exact answer...just to clear some reasoning)

Comment: Are you sure that it's an answer?

Comment: Yes I am. ..this gets really easy with graphical method. Draw the curve of 1/x and you will get it

Comment: @MansiTyagi You shouldn't be that sure, seriously. Your method can be great to give a supporting diagram to help to understand some reasoning, but it is not **at all** a proof and thus not an answer.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks for pointing out my mistake.. I'm sorry..and i edited the  explanation.