# Proving that the Gamma function(infinite product) satisfies $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, infinite-product

In my book, the Gamma function is defined as $$\Gamma (z)=\frac{1}{g(z)}$$ where $$g(z)=e^{\gamma z}\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\{(1+z/n)e^{-z/n}\}$$ for a suitable choice of $\gamma$ such that $g(1)=1$. In the proof of the functional equation for this gamma function, what is shown is that $$\frac{g(z)}{zg(z+1)}=e^{-\gamma}\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\{\frac{n}{n+1}\exp(1/n)\}$$

My question is: Why does this imply that $g(z)=czg(z+1)$ for some constant c?

Comment: $c$ is equal to the expression on the right of your equation.

Comment: @cheerful parsnip But are we sure that it is finite?

Comment: Presumably your book proved convergence of the product when it defined $g$.

Comment: The product has an index $k$ but I assume it should be an $n$

Comment: @masin Correct. I'm still not exactly sure how to conclude c is finite though. I know that the infinite product of $g$ is finite for every fixed $z\in \mathbb{C}$. In fact, it is shown that the infinite product converges locally uniformly for any sequence of different complex numbers $a_n$ (so $a_n=-n$ in this case).

Comment: Right. You can google "[Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) convergence" and there should be many arguments. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629630/simple-proof-euler-mascheroni-gamma-constant) is an argument from within MSE.

Answer (score 1):

So the question is:

> How do we know $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}e^{\frac{1}{n}}$ converges?

$\prod_{n=1}^\infty a_n $ converges  $ \iff 
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ln(a_n)$ converges.

So apply the natural log to the product

$$ \begin{align}
&\ln\bigg(\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}e^{\frac{1}{n}} \bigg) \\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(n)-\ln(n+1)+1/n \\ &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg( \frac{1}{n} -\int_{n}^{n+1} dt/t  \bigg)
\\& =\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{x}-\int_1^N dt/t \\ & =\gamma 
\end{align}$$

And this is the famous [Euler Mascheroni Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant). You can find a proof that this converges over [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629630/simple-proof-euler-mascheroni-gamma-constant).