# Doubt on $\ln k!$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How did the following equation follow?

$$\ln1+\ln2+\dots+\ln k\ge \int_{x=1}^k\ln x\mathop{dx}=k\ln k-k+1$$

I need to show $\binom{n}{k}<\frac{1}{e}\left(\frac{en}{k}\right)^k$.

But we have $\binom{n}{k}<\frac{n^k}{k!}$.

Comment: Can you explain more your issue? Do you have issue with proving the first line inequation? Do you have issue using this inequation to prove the second inequation. What about the third inequation? Why does it stands here?

Comment: See [my answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629630/simple-proof-euler-mascheroni-gamma-constant/629681#629681), for example.

Comment: Break the integral into $k$ pieces, over the intervals $[j.j+1]$ (for $1\leq j\<k$) and note that, on $[j.j+1]$, the integrand $\ln x$ is $\geq\ln j$.

Comment: Can you prove/argue why $\ln m \ge \int_{x=m-1}^m \ln x\ dx$?  (Hint: $\ln x$ is monotonically increasing so for any $x \in [m-1, m]$ we have $\ln x \le \ln m$ so $\int_{x=m-1} \ln x\ dx \le \int_{x=m-1}^m \ln m\ dx$.  Hint 2: $\ln m$ is a *constant*)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\ln n=\int_{n-1}^n\ln n\mathop{dx}$ for all $n=2,3,\dots, k$. Therefore,

\begin{align*}
\ln 1+\ln 2+\ln 3+\dots+\ln k&=0+\int_{1}^2\ln 2\mathop{dx}+\int_{2}^3\ln 3\mathop{dx}+\dots+\int_{k-1}^k\ln k\mathop{dx}\\
&\ge \int_{1}^2\ln x\mathop{dx}+\int_{2}^3\ln x\mathop{dx}+\dots+\int_{k-1}^k\ln x\mathop{dx}\\
&=\int_{1}^k\ln x\mathop{dx}.
\end{align*}

This inequality occurs since $\ln x$ is a strictly increasing function.