# Logarithmic Integral Inequality

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, summation

Give a convincing argument that the following inequalities are true:
$$\int_1^n \log x\mathrm dx \leq \log1 + \log2 + ... \log n \leq \int_1^{n+1}\log x \mathrm dx$$
for any $n \geq 1 $ . We are given the hint to observe that:
$$\int_{k-1}^k \log x\mathrm dx \leq \log k \leq \int_k^{k+1}\log x\mathrm dx $$

### Update 1

BRIC-Fan's argument makes sense but I'm supposed to use the result of the above inequality to show that:
$$ n^ne^{1-n} \leq n! \leq (n+1)^{n+1}e^{-n} $$

My apologies if this is trivial but could someone please help bridge the gap?

Comment: If you accept the hint, can't you just add up integrals, e.g., $\int_1^2 + \int_2^3 = \int_1^3$

Comment: Since $\log$ is an increasing function, $\log k \cdot ((k+1) - k) \leq \int_{k}^{k+1} \log(x) dx \leq \log(k+1) \cdot ((k+1) - k)$.

Comment: Try to draw a picture and compare the sum with the area under logarithm curve. Like in the pictures [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451558/how-to-find-the-sum-of-this-series-1-frac12-frac13-frac14-do/451668#451668) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/857473/convergence-nth-harmonic-number-minus-the-natural-logarithm-of-n/857485#857485).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the ways to apply this hint is notice that $n! = e^{\log n!} = e^{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log k} <e^{\int_{1}^{n+1} \log x dx} = e^{(n+1) \log (n+1)  -n} = e^{\log (n+1)^{n+1}} \cdot e^{-n}$

Answer (score 3):

**hint**: $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{k-1}^k \log xdx \leq \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \log k \leq \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{k}^{k+1} \log xdx$