# Does the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[\ln\left(1+\frac{x}{k}\right) - \frac{x}{k} \right]$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I tried all the theorems, that I knew in analysis, to know if the mentioned series converge but none of them is relevant except one: The Ratio Test for Series, but unfortunately this is not working as the limit is neither less nor greater than $1$, i.e.,  $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|} = \dfrac{\Big|\ln\Big(1+\dfrac{x}{n+1}\Big) - \dfrac{x}{n+1} \Big|}{\Big|\ln\Big(1+\dfrac{x}{n}\Big) - \dfrac{x}{n} \Big|} = 1.$$

How can I prove if the series $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[\ln\left(1+\frac{x}{k}\right) - \frac{x}{k} \right]$$ is convergent or not?

Thank you.

Edit - $x \in \mathbb{R} - {\{0, -1, -2, \dots}\}$. Same domain for $\Gamma (x)$. Please read [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1614084/show-that-the-gamma-function-converges).

Comment: $$-\frac{x^2}{2k^2}\leqslant\ln\left(1+\frac{x}{k}\right) - \frac{x}{k} \leqslant0\qquad(k\geqslant x)$$

Comment: IOW Taylor's theorem on $\ln(1+u)$.

Comment: @Did - I got the question (OP) when I read [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1614084/show-that-the-gamma-function-converges). No obligation of $k \ge x$ for $x$ exists except for $x$ is a nonzero nonnegative real number. Will it change the convergancy?

Comment: @Edi For every fixed $x$, $k \geq x$ holds *eventually* (that is, for sufficiently large $k$) so it's fine.

Comment: @Soke, Yes! Thanks a lot. Problem solved! :))

Comment: "Edit - $x \in \mathbb{R} - {\{0, -1, -2, \dots}\}$" No, rather $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $x>-1$.