# Euler's constant greater than 0 for all values of n?

Tags: calculus

If Euler's constant is described as the limit as n approaches infinity of the following:

$$t_n = 1 + \frac 12 + \frac 13 \cdots + \frac1n -\ln(n)$$

How can one prove that $t_n$ is greater than $0$ for all values of $n$?

Thanks!

Comment: This may help (Harmonic Number):http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748196/1-1-2-1-3-1-n also see:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

Comment: Your title is unsettling: Euler's constant does not depend on n.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First we have

$$\log (k+1)-\log k=\int_k^{k+1}\frac{1}{u}\,du\le \frac{1}{k} \tag 1$$

Next, we can sum both sides of $(1)$ to reveal that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\log (k+1)-\log k\right)=\log (n+1)\le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\tag 2$$

Thus, we see that $(2)$ implies that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}-\log (n+1)\ge 0$$

and therefore

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}-\log n > 0$$

Comment: Could you give more detail on how you made the jump between each step? Im not great at this subject at all.. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sure.  We used the definition of the log function $\log x=\int_1^x \frac{1}{u}\,du$ and the fact that $\frac{1}{u}\le \frac{1}{k}$ when $k\le u\le k+1$.  We summed a telescoping sum $\sum_{k=1}^n(\log(k+1)-\log k)=(\log(n+1)-\log n)+(\log n-\log (n-1))+(\log (n-1)-\log (n-2))\,\cdots +(\log (2)-\log (1))=\log (n+1)$.  Finally, we used the fact that $\log (n+1)>\log(n)$

Comment: Ahh I see! Thank you!!

Comment: Why the down vote??  Whoever gave this a down vote, please explain.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: (+1) I am often baffled by the downvotes to good answers. It is best not to dwell on them, and not to expect most downvoters to explain. Only rarely has a downvoter explained their vote, but when they do, I always appreciate it since it allows me to improve my answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, put $s_n = 1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\cdots + \dfrac{1}{n}$, then

$1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\cdots + \dfrac{1}{n} - \ln n > 0$ because:

$1 = \displaystyle \int_{1}^2 1dx \geq \displaystyle \int_{1}^2 \dfrac{1}{x}dx$,

$\dfrac{1}{2} = \displaystyle \int_{2}^3 \dfrac{1}{2}dx \geq \displaystyle \int_{2}^3 \dfrac{1}{x}dx$, and

$.....$

$\dfrac{1}{n-1} = \displaystyle \int_{n-1}^n \dfrac{1}{n-1}dx\geq \displaystyle \int_{n-1}^n \dfrac{1}{x}dx$, and add these integrals we have:

$s_n = s_{n-1} + \dfrac{1}{n} \geq \displaystyle \int_{1}^n \dfrac{1}{x}dx + \dfrac{1}{n}=\ln n + \dfrac{1}{n} > \ln n\Rightarrow t_n = s_n - \ln n > 0$

Answer (score 2):

By [Abel's summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) $$\sum_{k\leq n}\frac{1}{k}=1+\int_{1}^{n}\frac{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor }{t^{2}}dt\geq1+\int_{1}^{n}\frac{t-1}{t^{2}}dt=\log\left(n\right)+\frac{1}{n}>\log\left(n\right)
 $$ where $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor 
 $ is the floor function.

Answer (score 1):

Since the function $x \mapsto 1/x: ]0, \infty[ \to \mathbb{R}$ is strictly decreasing, we have $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} > \int_{x=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{x} = \log (n+1)$ for all $n \geq 1$. But, since $\log (n+1) > \log n$ for all $n \geq 1$, we have $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} - \log n > 0$ for all $n \geq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $1+x\le e^x$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we have that $\log(1+x)\le x$ for $x\gt-1$. Thus, for $x=-\frac1n$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1n-\log\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)
&=\log\left(1-\frac1n\right)-\left(-\frac1n\right)\\
&\le0\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Inequality $(1)$ means that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k-\log(n)\tag{2}
$$
is a decreasing sequence.

However, using the standard comparison of sum and integral of a decreasing function,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k
&\ge\int_1^{n+1}\frac1x\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\log(n+1)\\[8pt]
&\ge\log(n)\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

> Inequality $(3)$ answers the question. In addition, it shows that $(2)$ is not only a decreasing sequence, but also bounded below by $0$. This means that $(2)$ decreases to a non-negative limit.

This limit is known as $\gamma$, the [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), and a fairly simple and efficient method for computing $\gamma$ is derived in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/344574/13854).