# Monotonicity of $a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k - \ln n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to show that $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} - \ln n$ is decreasing. Can someone help please?

Comment: Compare http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344314/showing-that-lim-n-to-infty-sumn-k-1-frac1k-lnn-0-5772-ldots.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't find that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac1k - \ln(n+1)\right) - \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac1k - \ln n \right) = \frac{1}{n+1} + \ln\frac{n}{n+1}$$
but
$$
\ln\frac{n}{n+1} = \ln\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right) \leq -\frac{1}{n+1}
$$
since $\ln(1+x) \leq x$.

For the last inequality, if it is not known: easy to show by convexity. Consider $f\colon x\mapsto \ln(1+x)$, which has $f(0)=0$, $f^\prime(0) = 1$, and is concave, so that $f(x) \leq f(0) + f^\prime(0)x$ for all $x \geq -1$).

Comment: Or use the series for $\ln (1 - x)$

Comment: Sure -- but that presupposes either a bit more knowledge, or a bit more faith in authority, than the simpler inequality above require. 
For reference:
$$
\ln(1-x) = -\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k} =  -x - \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k}
$$
so for $x \geq 0$ we get
$$
\ln(1-x) \leq -x.
$$

Answer (score 4):

Set
$$
u_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k - \log(n),
$$ then,
$$
u_n-u_{n+1}=\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)-\frac1{n+1}, \quad n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$ Now observe that
$$
\log\left(1+x\right)-\frac{x}{1+x}\geq0, \quad x \in [0,1].\tag1
$$ To see $(1)$, just consider the derivative,
$$
\left(\log\left(1+x\right)-\frac{x}{1+x}\right)'=\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}\geq0,\quad x \in [0,1]
$$ and the fact that
$$\left(\log\left(1+x\right)-\frac{x}{1+x}\right)_{x=0}=0.$$

Then apply $(1)$ with $x=\dfrac1n$ to obtain $u_n-u_{n+1}\geq0$.

Comment: Your inequality can also be shown by the mean value theorem.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Yes, Rene.