# On the harmonic number ($H_n$) upper and lower "classical" bounds: which of those is closest to $H_n$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, discrete-mathematics

It is a well-known fact that the harmonic number

$$\displaystyle H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$$

satisfies the following inequality:

$$\displaystyle \ln(n) + \frac{1}{n} \;\leq \; H_n \; \leq \; \ln(n) + 1$$

as it is stated on page 26 of [this notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/readings/MIT6_042JF10_chap09.pdf).

Is it true that $H_n$ is closer to $\ln(n) + 1$ than $H_n$ is to $\displaystyle \ln(n) + \frac{1}{n}$? If so, how to prove that?

Comment: Use an integration

Comment: I have tried, but how exactly should I do this? I mean, in which variable? What should be the limits of integration?

Comment: Draw graph of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: I did, but how does this help in seeing that $H_n$ is closer to $\ln(n) + 1$ than $H_n$ is to $\displaystyle \ln(n) + \frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: Look at page 11 of: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/readings/MIT6_042JF10_chap09.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got a proof.
The area under $1/x$ from 1 to $n$

$\;\displaystyle \int_{1}^n \frac{1}{x}\, dx = \ln n\;$

could be bounded by using the trapezoidal rule.
As a result,

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{k+1}\right)1 \; \; > \;\; \ln n$

which implies that

$\displaystyle H_n \;\; > \;\; \ln n \,+\, \frac{1}{2} \,+\, \frac{1}{2n}$

by using the definition of $H_n$ in the summation.

Comment: That is precisely the solution I provided for you 5 hours previously.  ;-))

Answer (score 15):

Note that since $\frac1x$ is convex, then we have

$$\log(n)=\int_1^n\frac1x\,dx<\frac12+\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\frac1k+\frac1{2n}\tag1$$

Rearranging $(1)$ reveals

$$H_n-\log(n)>\frac12+\frac1{2n}>\frac12$$

Therefore, we have

$$H_n>\log(n)+\frac12$$

Comment: Thank you, Mark Viola, but I didn't understand your first inequality. Why doest the fact that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x}$ is convex implies it?

Comment: @DiegoS.Rodrigues: by the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality),if we approximate the integral of a positive and convex function through the trapezoid method we get an upper bound on the actual value of the integral.

Comment: Yes, this helped me, but the Hermite-Hadamard Inequality gives $\displaystyle \int_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{x} dx \; \leq \; (n-1) \displaystyle \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)$ as a result, and I couldn't proceed to get the inequality (1).

Comment: @Diego S. Rodrigues: use Hermite-Hadamard's inequality on each interval $[k,k+1]$ (with $1 \leq k < n$), then sum the inequalities you get.

Answer (score 8):

Consider the sequence $H_n-\log(n)$. Jensen's Inequality says
$$
\begin{align}
(H_n-\log(n))-(H_{n+1}-\log(n+1))
&=\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)-\frac1{n+1}\\
&=\int_n^{n+1}\frac1x\,\mathrm{d}x-\frac1{n+1}\\
&\ge\left(\int_n^{n+1}x\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{-1}-\frac1{n+1}\\
&=\frac1{n+\frac12}-\frac1{n+1}\\
&=\frac1{(2n+1)(n+1)}\\
&\ge\frac1{(2n+1)\left(n+\frac32\right)}\\
&=\frac1{2n+1}-\frac1{2n+3}\tag1
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $H_n-\log(n)$ is a decreasing sequence and the limit is $\gamma$, the [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Furthermore, summing $(1)$ yields
$$
H_n-\log(n)\ge\gamma+\frac1{2n+1}\tag2
$$
As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/344574), $\gamma=0.57721566490153286060651209$. Thus, $H_n-\log(n)$ is closer to $1$ than to $\frac1n$ for $n\ge2$.

---

We can get an upper bound on $H_n-\log(n)$ as follows
$$
\begin{align}
(H_n-\log(n))-(H_{n+1}-\log(n+1))
&=\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)-\frac1{n+1}\\
&=\int_0^{1/n}\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\le\int_0^{1/n}x\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1{2n^2}\\
&\le\frac1{2n-1}-\frac1{2n+1}\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Summing $(3)$ yields
$$
H_n-\log(n)\le\gamma+\frac1{2n-1}\tag4
$$

Comment: Nice. I needed the upper bound for my article [Tatuzawa and Iseki Prove Selberg's Inequality](https://nonagon.org/ExLibris/tatuzawa-iseki-prove-selbergs-inequality#bound-harmonic-series), where I copied and cited this proof.