# Find the value of $T=\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {\left( {1+ \frac{{1+\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}+ . +\frac{1}{n}}}{{{n^2}}}} \right)^n}$

Tags: limits

I am trying to evaluate

$$T = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {\left( {1 + \frac{{1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n}}}{{{n^2}}}} \right)^n}.$$

My solution is as follow

$$T = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {\left( {1 + \frac{{1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n}}}{{{n^2}}}} \right)^n} \Rightarrow T = {e^{\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } n\left( {1 + \frac{{1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n}}}{{{n^2}}} - 1} \right)}} = {e^{\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \left( {\frac{{1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n}}}{n}} \right)}}$$

$$T = {e^{\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \left( {\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{{2n}} + \frac{1}{{3n}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{{{n^2}}}} \right)}} = {e^{\left( {0 + 0 + \cdots + 0} \right)}} = {e^0} = 1$$

The solution is correct  but I presume my approach $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \left( {\frac{{1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdot + \frac{1}{n}}}{n}} \right) \Rightarrow \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \left( {\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{{2n}} + \frac{1}{{3n}} + \cdot + \frac{1}{{{n^2}}}} \right) = 0$ is wrong.

Is there any generalized method

Comment: One approach is to use Cesaro-Stolz and show that $(1+1/2+\dots+1/n)/n\to 0$.

Comment: Use \cdot for $\cdots$ instead of using periods. They do not work so great with $\rm\LaTeX$.

Comment: @Cameron Williams. How did you write latex that way in your comment?

Comment: @RanjitKumarSarkar \rm\LaTeX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If
$$T = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {\left( {1 + \frac{{1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + . + \frac{1}{n}}}{{{n^2}}}} \right)^n}$$
then
$$\log T = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } n\log{\left( {1 + \frac{H_n}{{{n^2}}}} \right)}\le \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{H_n}{n}.$$
It can be easily shown that this limit tends to $0$ (for example by Cesaro-Stolz.) So
$$\log T \le 0 \Rightarrow \log T = 0 \Rightarrow T=1.$$

---

**Addendum:** Showing that $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{H_n}{n}\to0$.

*Cesaro-Stolz:*

We may set $a_n=H_n$ and $b_n={n}$. (We can apply Cesaro-Stolz since $(n)_{n\ge 1}$ is strictly monotone and divergent. The limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{H_{n+1}-H_n}{n+1-n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+1},$$
exists so
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{H_n}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0.$$

*Bounding $H_n$*

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2534053/on-the-harmonic-number-h-n-upper-and-lower-classical-bounds-which-of-thos) question a user proved $H_n<\log(n)+1.$ That means that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{H_n}{n}\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)+1}{n}=0.$$
Since our oringal limit is non-negative we can conclude $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{H_n}{n}=0$.

*l'hopital*

One may also stick to the classic l'hopital. Differentiating numerator and denominator yields
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{H_n}{n}=\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{\pi^2/6-H_n^{(2)}}{1}.$$
Since $H_n^{(2)}\to\pi^2/6$ for $n\to\infty$, the overall limit equals zero too.

Comment: You might want to describe which extension of $H_n$ you are using in order to take its derivative.

Answer (score 4):

**Problem with the Approach in the Question**

One must take extra care when taking the limit of the sum of an increasing number of terms, each of which is tending to $0$. For example,
$$
\overbrace{\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{n+2}+\frac1{n+3}+\cdots+\frac1{n+n}}^{\text{$n$ terms, each of which tends to $0$}}
$$
If we sum the limits of each term, we get $0$. However, each of the $n$ terms is $\ge\frac1{2n}$, therefore, the $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}$ of the sum is $\ge\frac12$.

---

**Inequalities and the Limit**

First, we have the bound
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k
&\le1+\sum_{k=2}^n\int_{k-1}^k\frac{\mathrm{d}x}x\tag{1a}\\
&=1+\int_1^n\frac{\mathrm{d}x}x\tag{1b}\\[6pt]
&=1+\log(n)\tag{1c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a)}$: $\frac1k\le\int_{k-1}^k\frac{\mathrm{d}x}x$
$\text{(1b)}$: the sum of an integral over disjoint intervals
$\phantom{\text{(1b):}}$ is the integral over the union of those intervals
$\text{(1c)}$: integrate

Furthermore, for $x\gt-1$ and $n\ge1$ and $nx\lt1$,
$$
\begin{align}
(1+x)^n
&\le\left(\frac1{1-x}\right)^n\tag{2a}\\
&\le\frac1{1-nx}\tag{2b}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a)}$: $(1+x)(1-x)=1-x^2\le1$
$\text{(2b)}$: [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) applied to the reciprocal

Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k}{n^2}\right)^n
&\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1+\log(n)}{n^2}\right)^n\tag{3a}\\
&\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{1-\frac{1+\log(n)}n}\tag{3b}\\[3pt]
&=1\tag{3c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a)}$: apply $(1)$
$\text{(3b)}$: apply $(2)$
$\text{(3c)}$: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+\log(n)}n=0$

Therefore, since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k}{n^2}\right)^n\ge1$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k}{n^2}\right)^n=1\tag4
$$

Answer (score 3):

Consider the partial term
$$T_n=\left(1+\frac{H_n}{n^2}\right)^n\implies \log(T_n)=n \log\left(1+\frac{H_n}{n^2}\right)$$
For large $n$
$$H_n=\log (n)+\gamma +\frac{1}{2 n}-\frac{1}{12 n^2}+\frac{1}{120
   n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right)$$
$$\log\left(1+\frac{H_n}{n^2}\right)=\frac{\log (n)+\gamma }{n^2}+\frac{1}{2 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$
$$\log(T_n)=\frac{\log (n)+\gamma }{n}+\frac{1}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$T_n=e^{\log(T_n)}=1+\frac{\log (n)+\gamma }{n}+\frac{(\log (n)+\gamma )^2+1}{2
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.

Moreover, this give a shortcut method for the evaluation of $T_n$. Suppose $n=10$. The exact value is
$$T_{10}=\left(\frac{259381}{252000}\right)^{10} \sim 1.334677$$ while the above truncated series gives $\sim 1.334446$ (relative error $=0.017$%).

Answer (score 2):

You can crudely bound $1+\frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n}$ by
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} \le \sum_{k=1}^{\lceil\sqrt{n}\rceil} \frac{1}{k} + \sum_{k=\lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil}^n \frac{1}{k} \le \lceil \sqrt{n}\rceil \cdot 1 + n \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \le 3\sqrt{n},$$
so that when you divide this by $n$, the expression is bounded by $3 \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n} \to 0$.

Comment: True, but not useful.

Comment: @IgorRivin How is that not useful? This means the limit is $0$ by squeeze theorem, replacing the suspect step.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is incorrect. The good solution is that $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k \sim \log n,$ so that

$$ 1\leq T = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {\left( {1 + \frac{{1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + . + \frac{1}{n}}}{{{n^2}}}} \right)^n} \leq \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty }\left(1 + \frac{\log n}{n^2} \right)^n$$

For any $k,$ there exists an $N,$ such that $\frac{\log n}{n^2} \leq \frac{1}{k n}$ for $n>N,$ so

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty }\left(1 + \frac{\log n}{n^2} \right)^n \leq \exp(\frac1k).$$ It follows that $T=1.$

Answer (score 2):

Your doubt is right - it is not possible to split limit in variable amount of summands, as shows example $1=\lim 1=\lim\left(\frac{1}{n}+\cdots + \frac{1}{n}\right)=\lim \frac{1}{n} +\cdots + \lim\frac{1}{n} = 0$.

On another way you can use representation

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}  = \ln n + \gamma + \varepsilon_{n}= \ln n +O(1), n\rightarrow \infty$$
where $ \varepsilon_{n} \sim \frac{1}{2n}, n\rightarrow \infty$ based on [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) $\gamma$. This also gives you $\frac{{1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + . + \frac{1}{n}}}{n} \to 0, n\rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

We want to show that $$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{H_n}{n}=0$$.

We have $\log n = \displaystyle \int_{1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{t} dt$. Also, $H_n = \displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{r} = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\frac{r}{n}}$

Thus, by comparison with the Riemann sums of $\log n$, we see that $\log n < H_n < 1 + \log n$.

So we get that, $$\dfrac{\log n}{n} < \dfrac{H_n}{n} < \dfrac{1+\log n}{n}$$

But both the left and right sides of the above inequality tend to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, and hence, by the Sandwich theorem (or Squeeze principle), $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{H_n}{n} = 0$$