# Does $a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin \frac{1}{k} - \ln n$ converge?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I have this sequence: $a_n = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \sin \frac{1}{k} - \ln n$ and I would like to show that it converges. How should I proceed with these kinds of question as I have only started learning about limits. I am quite sure that finding the limit is quite hard, so there must be some results I can use?

Comment: The most basic approach to show that a series converges (without finding the limit itself) is to prove that (1) the series is monotone (in this case, it is decreasing) and (2) it is bounded (in this case, bounded from below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will separate the limit in two parts

$$a_n=\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^n \sin\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)-\frac{1}{k}}_{b_n} + \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}-\ln(n)}_{c_n}$$

The sequence $c_n$ [converges to the Euler–Mascheroni Constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2790008/is-there-another-proof-for-euler-mascheroni-constant).

Now, for the sequence $b_n$, by Taylor $\sin(x)=x+o(x^2).$ Hence,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \sin\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)-\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^n o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
which converges as it can be compared with the sum in the Basel problem.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\sin(x) \approx x - \frac{x^3}{3!}$ when $x$ is close to $0$, this suggest to write $$\sum_{k=1}^n\sin\frac{1}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^n\left(\sin\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k}\right)+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$$
and the first sum will converge.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: As I have stated, I have only started studying limits and I don't understand the approximation.

Comment: andu, It seems this problem is too advanced for you.

Comment: I don't know what to say about that. I have googled the approximation and checked the curriculum for this year. We are not supposed to learn Taylor's Series until next year.