# $1-{1\over 2}+{1\over 3}-{1\over 4}+{1\over 5}-{1\over 6}+\dots-{1\over 2012}+{1\over 2013}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sum $1-{1\over 2}+{1\over 3}-{1\over 4}+{1\over 5}-{1\over 6}+\dots-{1\over 2012}+{1\over 2013}$ is equal,

a) ${1\over 1006}+{1\over 1007}+{1\over 1008}+\dots+{1\over 2013}$

b) ${1\over 1007}+{1\over 1008}+{1\over 1009}+\dots+{1\over 2013}$

c)${1\over 1006}+{1\over 1007}+{1\over 1008}+\dots +{1\over 2012}$

d) ${1\over 1007}+{1\over 1008}+{1\over 1009}+\dots+{1\over 2012}$

I tried by separating negatives and positives terms but did not get anything nice and simpler. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Look at the comments to [this answer by zyx](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/73563/11619).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is $\lim\limits\_{k\to\infty}\sum\limits\_{n=k+1}^{2k}{\frac{1}{n}} = 0$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73550/is-lim-limits-k-to-infty-sum-limits-n-k12k-frac1n-0)

Comment: Vote against closing. That an answer to another question answers this one doesn't mean it is automatically duplicate (what if I wanted to give a different answer to this question?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{1\le r\le 2n+1}(-1)^{r-1}\frac1r$$

$$=\sum_{1\le r\le 2n+1}\frac1r-2\left(\sum_{1\le r\le n-1}\frac1{2r}\right)$$

$$=\sum_{1\le r\le 2n+1}\frac1r-\left(\sum_{1\le r\le n-1}\frac1{r}\right)$$

$$=\sum_{n\le r\le 2n+1}\frac1r$$

Here $2n+1=2013\implies n=?$