# Limit and sum question

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, harmonic-numbers

Solve these limits.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\,\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2n}\,\right)=?$$

and $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n} = ?$ where

$$a_{0}=1\,,\quad a_{n}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\,\frac{2}{a_{n-1}}+a_{n-1}\,\right)$$

Comment: Please consider updating your question with some information about what you have tried or where you are getting stuck. You will find people are much more willing to help if you do!

Comment: I want to solve them without using Integral

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one?).

Comment: Your second question is answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82682/proof-of-convergence-babylonian-method-x-n1-frac12x-n-fracax-n

Comment: Your first question is answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73550/is-lim-limits-k-to-infty-sum-limits-n-k12k-frac1n-0

Comment: Thanks. I'll never send more than one question in same post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hiint:** For the first one you can use the Riemann sum

$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k} \frac{1}{1+k/n} \longrightarrow_{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^{1}\dots dx$$

For the second one, assume $\lim a_n = b$ and subs back in the eq. and solve for $b$.

Comment: Thanks.   I can solve them with Integral(answer==$\ln 2$).I want to solve them without Integral.I proved that it is decreasing and bounded below.But I couldn't find it's limit without Integral.

Answer (score 2):

Problem 1: compare
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}
$$
to 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{n}^{2n}\frac{dx}{x}=\log 2
$$

Problem 2: if the limit exists, it is equal to 
$$
x=\frac{1}{x} + \frac{x}{2}
$$
Can you handle from here?