# Find the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k+n}$

Tags: calculus, limits, harmonic-numbers

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k+n}$$

Could you please give me a hint how to find this limit?

Comment: See also [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/73550) and other posts which are [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/73550).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k+n} =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1{\dfrac kn+1}$$

Use   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n f\left(\frac rn\right)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

Comment: $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x} \Rightarrow \int f(x) = \ln (1+x) = \ln (1+1) - \ln (1) = \ln 2 $. Thanks! Could you tell me how do you figure out that extracting 1/n will lead to integral?

Comment: @Mirak, Observe that extracting $1/n$ gives us $f(k/n)$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k+n}~=~\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1k~=~\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac1k~-~\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k~=~H_{2n}-H_n~\simeq~\ln2n-\ln n~=~\ln\frac{2n}n$$ Can you take it from here, and evaluate what happens as $n\to\infty$ ? :-$)$

Comment: I think it's better to use $o(1)$ in this case instead of $\simeq$. $$H_n=\ln(n)+\gamma +o(1)$$
It's generally a bad idea to use $\simeq$ when subtracting two equivalent functions.