# $ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{4n - \frac{k^2}{n}} $ appears to disagree with $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{4-x^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

In question 1280454, t was asked how to find
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{4n - \frac{k^2}{n}} $$
and of course, you can write this as 
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{4 - \frac{k^2}{n^2}}
= \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{4-x^2}
$$ by using the variable $x=\frac{k}{n}$ in a Reimann integral.

However, 
$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{4-x^2} = \frac18\left(\ln(5)-\ln(3) \right) \approx 0.06385$$
while each of the $n$ terms in 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{4n - \frac{k^2}{n}}$$ exceeds $\frac{1}{4n}$ so the sum must be greater than $\frac{1}{4}$ in all cases.  (Experimentatlly, the limit is about $0.275$)

What gives???

Comment: How did you calculate the integral??? $\displaystyle \frac{1}{4-x^2}=\frac{1}{(2-x)(2+x)}=\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{2-x}+\frac{-\frac14}{2+x}$ using the Cover Up Method.

Comment: Note that the function $f(x)=1/(4-x^2)\gt1/4$ for all $x\in(0,1)$, so the integral $\int_0^1f(x)dx\gt1/4$ as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Computation error:

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{4-x^2} &= \frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2+x} + \frac{1}{2-x}\,dx\\
&= \frac{1}{4} \bigl[\log (2+x) - \log (2-x)\bigr]_0^1\\
&= \frac{1}{4}\bigl[\log 3 - \log 1 - \log 2 + \log 2\bigr]\\
&= \frac{1}{4}\log 3\\
&> \frac{1}{4}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks.  I'm humiliated by making such a silly error (I acted as if the $4$ was $4^2$

Answer (score 5):

$$\dfrac1{4n-\dfrac{k^2}n}=\dfrac n{4n^2-k^2}=\dfrac14\dfrac{2n+k+(2n-k)}{(2n+k)(2n-k)}=\dfrac14\left[\dfrac1{2n+k}+\dfrac1{2n-k}\right]$$

Now follow [Find the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k+n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279816/find-the-limit-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sum-k-1n-frac1kn)

Answer (score 3):

Otherwise from your method you should take $ a$ as 2 not 4 thus the integral evaluates to be 
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{4-x^2} = \frac1{2a}\left(\ln(\frac{a+(x=1)}{a-(x=1)})-\ln(\frac{a+(x=0)}{a-(x=0)}) \right) = \frac1{2*2}\left(\ln(\frac{2+1}{2-1})-\ln(\frac{2}{2}) \right) = \frac1{4}\ln3
$$

Comment: i have spent a lot of time on this question. Please do the honors.

Comment: What do you mean by "please do the honors"?

Comment: i meant a simple up vote as the answer is good and i had to browse through my text books to at last find the simple mistake Mark did. I don't mean to be rude. Not a problem i guess @OliverBegassat

Comment: I didn't take offence, but most people on here (not just you) put effort into their answers, are equally deserving of receiving upvotes yet don't ask for them. It's bad form in my opinion.

Comment: No I think you're correct to an extent but what I think is that it's how the site works you give something and you get something too