# A limit using integral to compute

Tags: calculus, integration

Is it possible to compute the following limit by using integral?
$$\lim_{n‎ ‎\rightarrow ‎\infty} ‎‎\left( ‎‎\dfrac{1}{n^2+1}+‎\dfrac{2}{n^2+2}+‎\cdots ‎+‎\dfrac{n}{n^2+n}‎‎‎\right)$$

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279816/find-the-limit-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sum-k-1n-frac1kn

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I think it is totally different from my question.

Comment: @user I have a problem to get the second term. $\dfrac{2}{n}‎\dfrac{1}{1+(‎\frac{2}{n})^2‎}$ is not correct.

Comment: Yes; but it's much easier to use \begin{align*}\dfrac{1}{n^2+n}+‎\dfrac{2}{n^2+n}+‎\cdots ‎+‎\dfrac{n}{n^2+n}‎‎‎ &< \dfrac{1}{n^2+1}+‎\dfrac{2}{n^2+2}+‎\cdots ‎+‎\dfrac{n}{n^2+n}‎‎‎ \\ &< \dfrac{1}{n^2}+‎\dfrac{2}{n^2}+‎\cdots ‎+‎\dfrac{n}{n^2}‎‎‎\end{align*}and use the squeeze theorem.

Comment: @GregMartin Yes. Thank you. It was beautiful.

Comment: See also: [$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac 1{n^2+1}+\frac 2{n^2+2}+\frac 3{n^2+3}+\cdots +\frac n{n^2+n}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2504491)