# $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac 1{n^2+1}+\frac 2{n^2+2}+\frac 3{n^2+3}+\cdots +\frac n{n^2+n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, proof-writing

**Evaluate:**

$$ L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac 1{n^2+1}+\frac 2{n^2+2}+\frac 3{n^2+3}+\cdots +\frac n{n^2+n}\right)$$

**My approach:**

Each term can be written as

$$ \frac k{n^2+k}=\frac {n^2+k-n^2}{n^2+k}=1-\frac {n^2}{n^2+k}$$

$$ \therefore \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac k{n^2+k}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1-\frac {n^2}{n^2+k}\right)=0$$

hence,

$$ L=0$$

**Problem:**

The correct answer is 1/2, please indicate the flaw in my approach or post a new solution.

Thank You

Comment: If $a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, then it doesn't mean $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_i a_i = 0$ right?

Comment: Your mistake is treating individual terms separately. As $n$ grows, each term does indeed become small, but there are more and more terms also, as $n$ grows. You need a way of talking about the whole sum that takes the number of terms into account, as well as their sizes.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026607/find-lim-n-to-infty-left-frac1n21-frac1n22-frac1n2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**HINT:**

Using $\sum_{k=1}^n k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ along with the estimates $n^2+1\le n^2+k\le n^2+n$ reveals

$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2(n^2+n)}\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n^2+k}\le \frac{n(n+1)}{2(n^2+1)}$$

Comment: What lead you to come to this inequality? What I would try to do, and get nowhere, is multiply the smallest term, $\frac{1}{n+1}$ , by n to get a lower bound, and the biggest term, $\frac{n}{n^2+n}$, also by n to get an upper bound. What was the intuition? How did you realize you were going for $\frac{1}{2}$ in the first place?

Comment: The bounds you apply only show that the series is bounded between $0$ and $1$.  Hence, we need something tighter.  The way I presented provides bounds that sqeeze the partial sums to be $1/2$.

Comment: Yeah, I understand, but my question was how you came up with these bounds. I'm asking this because I want to trace your line of thought, I'm relatively new to this as a freshman, and I want to be able to come up with better ideas than I do now. If you have the time to explain, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: It's evident that $1\le k\le n$ implies that $n^2+1\le n^2+k\le n^2+n$, is it not?  Using this, we proceed straightforwardly.  There isn't a lot of ingenuity, only a bit of circumspect.

Comment: The denominators of these fractions are all of the numbers from $n^2+1$ through $n^2+n$. If the denominators were all the same, we would have a nice formula to sum the numerators. We can obtain a lower bound by replacing each denominator with the largest one, and we can obtain an upper bound by making them all equal to the smallest one. When both of the resulting expressions have limit $1/2$, it's clear that our expression of interest has that limit, too. There's no need to realize that $1/2$ is the number you're going for - it just falls out of the calculation.

Comment: One thing that can help with the intuition: Since n^2 is the dominant term in the denominator, nothing in the limit is likely to be changed by fiddling with the other term. Whether the part after $n^2$ is always $+1$ or always $+n$ or a variety of numbers in-between, we get the same limit in any event.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs That's incredible. Thank you so much, that's a great explanation.

Answer (score 4):

*For a correct solution, see [Mark Viola's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2504500/75808). Here I explain why what you did does not yield the right answer.*

The issue in your approach: each term individually goes to $0$ when $n$ goes to infinity, indeed. But you sum $n$ of them, *and $n$ goes to infinity*.

So you sum a **large** number of **small** terms. Essentially, you get an indeterminate form $\infty\cdot 0$, explaining the discrepancy between what you wrote and the actual answer.

---

Also, a quick sanity check showing the answer **canno** be zero: assuming for convenience $n$ is even,
You have $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2+k} \geq \sum_{k=n/2+1}^n \frac{k}{n^2+k} \geq \sum_{k=n/2+1}^n \frac{\frac{n}{2}}{n^2+n} = \frac{n}{2}\frac{\frac{n}{2}}{n^2+n} = \frac{1}{4}\frac{n^2}{n^2+n} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \frac{1}{4}
$$
so the limit, if it exists (and it does) has to be at least $1/4$.

Comment: Nice explanation.  (+1)

Comment: I'd add that if OP's reasoning was correct, you would have things like $$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=1$$ Because every term goes to $1$ , but this doesn't apply as there are $n$ multiplicative terms, and we have of course $$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e$$. I always found this a nice example to illustrate this kind of flaw of reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{k \over n^{2} + k} & =
\underbrace{\qquad{1 \over n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{k \over n}\qquad}
_{\ds{\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\large\to} \int_{0}^{1}x\,\dd x = \color{red}{1 \over 2}}}\ -\
\overbrace{\qquad\underbrace{{1 \over n^{2}}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{k^{2} \over n^{2} + k}}_{\ds{>\ 0}}\qquad}
^{\ds{< {1 \over n^{2}}\,\pars{n^{2} \over n^{2} + 1}n}}\
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\large \to}\,\,\,
\bbx{1 \over 2}
\end{align}