# How to evaluate a limit with an inverse of a sum

Tags: calculus, integration

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{1 + ( \frac{i}{n})^2} $$

I know what this is as an integral, and it's supposed to evaluate to $\frac{\pi}{4}$. I'm not sure how to evaluate this as a limit though, and I want to know because I think it will broaden my understanding a bit.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279816/find-the-limit-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sum-k-1n-frac1kn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that it is a Riemann sum for $\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$:

Since $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is continuous, then it is integrable. Then, for any tagged partition $P=\{x_0=0,x_1,...,x_n=1\}$ with tags $x_{i_1}\le t_i\le x_i$, we have $$\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx=\lim_{\|P\|\to0}\sum_{i=1}^nf(t_i)(x_i-x_{i-1}).$$

In particular, if we take $P=\{0,1/n,2/n,...,n/n\}$ and $t_i=x_i$, $i\ge1$, we get $$\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nf(\frac{i}{n})\frac{1}{n},$$ which is your sum.

Thus, the limit is $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way of doing it the long way, i.e., manipulating the equation in such a way as to evaluate the limit and then be left with pi/4? That's what I'm trying to work on..

Comment: Good luck with that.Ask Ramanujan.

Comment: lol right on...