# To evaluate the limits $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \{\frac{1}{1+n^3}+\frac{4}{8+n^3}+\ldots +\frac{n^2}{n^3+n^3}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, riemann-sum

To me it seems like that we need to manipulate the given sum into the Riemann sum of some function. First writing in the standard summation form;

$$\{\frac{1}{1+n^3}+\frac{4}{8+n^3}+\ldots +\frac{n^2}{n^3+n^3}\}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{k^2}{k^3+n^3}$$

I have tried factoring out $\frac{1}{n}$ from the above sum. But I cant seem to get into the right form. Any help!

Comment: You can use sandwich law. What is the biggest numerator? and what is the smallest denominator? How can you bound the sum?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279816/find-the-limit-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sum-k-1n-frac1kn  and observe : $$\frac{k^2}{k^3+n^3}=\dfrac1n\cdot\dfrac{(k/n)^2}{(k/n)^3+1}$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee That seems to do it. The answer turns out to be $\int_{0}^1 \frac{x^2}{1+x^3} = \frac{1}{3} \log 2$.

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee: Hmmm... It seems I'm very slow in using mathjax :( Please turn your comment as an answer; I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 4):

You can proceed from here as $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{k^2}{k^3+n^3}= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \;\frac{1}{n}\frac{\frac{k^2}{n^2}}{\frac{k^3}{n^3}+1}= \lim_{h\to 0} \;h\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{{(kh)}^2}{1 + {(kh)}^3}= \int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{1+x^3} \mathrm{d}x\;.$$

Comment: Wow! Lab bhattacharjee has answered it already. ; /

Comment: Why the downvote? It seems it is wrong to post a right answer, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$\frac{k^2}{k^3+n^3}=\dfrac1n\cdot\dfrac{\left( \frac{k}{n} \right)^2}{\left( \frac{k}{n} \right)^3+1}$$
so you can rewrite the summation to be
$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to \infty} \Big(\frac{1}{1+n^3}+\frac{4}{8+n^3}+\ldots +\frac{n^2}{n^3+n^3}\Big) &= \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{k^2}{k^3+n^3}\\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \dfrac1n\cdot\dfrac{\left( \frac{k}{n} \right)^2}{\left( \frac{k}{n} \right)^3+1}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0} \;h\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{{(kh)}^2}{1 + {(kh)}^3}\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{1+x^3} \mathrm{d}x\;\\
&= \frac{1}{3} \ln(1+x^3) \Big|_0^1\\
&=  \frac{1}{3} \ln 2
\end{align}$$

Comment: You are late :P

Comment: yup, ahhaha sorry I just seen all answers :(