# How to evaluate $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\sum _{i=1}^n\:\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{2i}{n}}\right)\frac{2}{n}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

It's the first time that I'm in front of a limit of this kind: i mean with a summation inside. It must solve as a summation?. I have no idea how to solve it. Could you please help me? Thanks
$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\sum _{i=1}^n\:\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{2i}{n}}\right)\frac{2}{n}\right)$$

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279816/find-the-limit-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sum-k-1n-frac1kn

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$2\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+2x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{2}\sqrt{1+z}\,dz = \left.\frac{2}{3}(1+z)^{3/2}\right|_{0}^{2}=\color{red}{2\sqrt{3}-\frac{2}{3}.}$$
Your sum is a Riemann sum associated with the integral in the LHS.