# Limit of trigonometric series and integrals

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, riemann-sum

I found this problem many years ago, and I still doubt my solution:

> Find $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi
> k-\pi}{n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$$

I tried solve it by Riemann sums, but the third $\sin$ is not helpful.

Any help or hint?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I have not done the calculation, so this is pure speculation. One can express the product of two sines and/or cosines as a sum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The third sine approaches its argument in the limit as $n \to \infty$.  In this case, the sum takes the value

$$\begin{align}\int_0^1 dx \, x \, \sin^2{2 \pi x} &= \frac14  - \frac12 \int_0^1 dx \, x \, \cos{4 \pi x}\\ &= \frac14 + \frac1{8 \pi} \int_0^1 dx \, \sin{4 \pi x} \\ &= \frac14 \end{align}$$

Comment: Excelent!! Indeed my answer was $\int_0^{2\pi}x\sin^2xdx$. Is a typing error?

Comment: @sinbadh: no, mistake on my part.  Fixed.

Comment: Ron. +1 And congratulations on joining the 100-K Club.  Did you receive total consciousness yet?  ;-))  - Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV: Thanks!  Actually, since I attained 100K over the weekend, I have been sleeping 3 ft above my bed and have been looking for the Keymaster.  Oh, and there is no Ron, only Zuul.

Comment: @RonGordon. Very sincere congratulations for joining the 100-K Club !

Comment: @RonGordon, Congratulations on reaching $100$k. Could you please explain the steps assuming  I know http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279816/find-the-limit-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sum-k-1n-frac1kn

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: very sincere thank you!

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Thank you.  I'm sorry, but I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @RonGordon, By comparing with $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n f\left(\frac rn\right)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$ I understood $\dfrac kn$ transforms to $x$  but how $$\sin^22\pi x$$ has been arrived and there is no $\dfrac1n$  right?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: one of the sines has $2 \pi (k/n)$ as an argument; the other has $2 \pi (k/n) - (\pi/n)$.  The $(\pi/n)$ vanishes compared to $2 \pi (k/n)$ as $n \to \infty$.