# Proving convergence of sum to 2n

Tags: convergence-divergence

I need to prove that the following sequence converges as $n\to\infty$:
$\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{2n} 1/k$

The problem is that I've only ever seen sums from i to n for example. I'm confused because not only is 2n alien to me, but also k and n are related.

So far I've tried substituting k for n+1 to simplify the expression, but it led nowhere. I also tried to enter this into spreadsheet calculation in hopes to get an idea where the border might be, but the result just grows and grows. I almost expected this because the sequence is reminiscent of the harmonic series which diverges. The key difference is obviously the beginning and end of the sum, but I can't figure out how to tackle this.

Any ideas or pointers are appreciated

Comment: You're summing a finite number of terms, hence your final sum will be finite and it will converge.

Comment: Use the Squeeze Theorem

Comment: @EA304GT I think the sum is the $n$th term in a sequence

Comment: @EA304GT: I'm afraid things are not so simple. To take an obvious counter-example, if the summation term was $1$ instead of $1/k$, the sequence would be $(1,2,3,\ldots)$, which certainly doesn't converge.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/73550/11619)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The limit of truncated sums of harmonic series, $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=k+1}^{2k}{\frac{1}{n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73550/the-limit-of-truncated-sums-of-harmonic-series-lim-limits-k-to-infty-sum-n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that you sum $n$ terms in the sum, hence you can estimate the sum by $n$ times the biggest term, hence you get
$$
\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}\leqslant \frac{n}{n+1}\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}1
$$
Hence the sequence is bounded and since it is monotonically increasing the convergence follows.

Comment: The assertion that the sequence is monotonically increasing could use a bit of justification.

Comment: So I don't need to find out how it is bounded? I can simply claim it is, because there is a greater example?

Comment: @Eric: Yes, I'm sorry for being a bit sloppy but it is explained now in another answer.

Comment: @John: it is clearly bounded by $1$!

Answer (score 0):

Let us write $a_n=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} 1/k$, and let's compare $a_n$ to $a_{n+1}$.  They have almost the same terms, except $a_n$ has one more term at the beginning and $a_{n+1}$ has two more terms at the end.  We get that $$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}-\frac{1}{n+1}>\frac{1}{2n+2}+\frac{1}{2n+2}-\frac{1}{n+1}=0.$$

Thus the numbers $a_n$ are increasing.  Now note that for each $n$, every term in the sum for $a_n$ is at most $1/(n+1)$, and there are $n$ terms, so $a_n\leq n/(n+1)<1$.  So the sequence $a_n$ is monotone increasing and bounded above by $1$.  It follows that it must converge.