# Show that the following sequence $\{x_n\}$ is increasing and bounded above, and hence convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, harmonic-numbers

> Show that the following sequence $\{x_n\}$ is increasing and bounded above, and hence convergent. $x_n = \frac{1}{ n + 1} +\frac{ 1}{ n + 2} + · · · +\frac{ 1}{ 2n }$.

I need to find how the sequence converges by showing how it increases and is bounded above.

Comment: Do you mean $x_n = {1 \over n+1}+{1 \over n+2}+...+{1 \over 2n}$?

Comment: Can you show one of the two yet?

Comment: [This post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73550/is-lim-limits-k-to-infty-sum-limits-n-k12k-frac1n-0) deals with the same sequence. Other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/73550) might be of interest for you, too.

Answer (score 3):

**Hints:**

- Increasing:
  $$\begin{align}
  x_{n-1} &= \frac{1}{ n} +\frac{ 1}{ n + 1} + \dots +\frac{ 1}{ 2n-2 } \\ 
  x_n &= \frac{1}{ n + 1} +\frac{ 1}{ n + 2} + \dots +\frac{ 1}{ 2n }
  \end{align}$$
  so $x_n = x_{n-1} + \frac{ 1}{ 2n } + \frac{ 1}{ 2n -1 } - \frac{ 1}{ n }$. Can you show that $$\frac{ 1}{ 2n } + \frac{ 1}{ 2n -1 } - \frac{ 1}{ n } > 0$$
  ?
- Bounded above:
  To get $x_n$, you sum $n$ terms, each of them being less than $\frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1k
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\color{#C00000}{\frac1k}-\sum_{k=1}^n\color{#00A000}{\frac1k}\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\color{#C00000}{\frac1{2k-1}+\frac1{2k}}-\color{#00A000}{\frac1k}\right)\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1{2k-1}-\frac1{2k}\right)\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k(2k-1)}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, as a sum of positive terms, the sum increases with $n$.

Comparing to a telescoping series,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k(2k-1)}
&=\frac12+\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{2k(2k-1)}\tag{5}\\
&\le\frac12+\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{2k(2k-2)}\tag{6}\\
&=\frac12+\frac14\sum_{k=2}^n\left(\frac1{k-1}-\frac1k\right)\tag{7}\\
&=\frac34\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_n$ be defined as above. We show $x_n$ is increasing by induction. For the base case 
$
x_1=1/2 <  1/3 + 1/4 = 7/12 = x_2 
$
Suppose $x_n \geq x_{n-1}$. We have the following:
$
x_{n+1} = x_n + \dfrac{1}{2n+1} + \dfrac{1}{2n+2} - \dfrac{1}{n+1} = x_n + \dfrac{1}{4n^2+6n+2}
$
Thus $x_{n+1} > x_n$ and the sequence is increasing. 
To show the sequence is bounded we note
$
x_n < 1/n + x_n = \sum_{k=n}^{2n} 1/k < \int_n^2n 1/x \, dx = \ln (2n) - \ln (n) = \ln (2)
$
Thus the series is increasing and bounded above and therefore convergent.

Answer (score -1):

$x_{n+1} - x_n=$
$= ( \frac{1}{ n + 2} +\frac{ 1}{ n + 3} + · · · +\frac{ 1}{ 2n }+\frac{ 1}{ 2n+1 }+\frac{ 1}{ 2n+2 })-( \frac{1}{ n + 1} +\frac{ 1}{ n + 2} + · · · +\frac{ 1}{ 2n })=$
$= \frac{ 1}{ 2n+1 }+\frac{ 1}{ 2n+2 }-\frac{1}{ n + 1} =$
$= \frac{ 1}{ 2n+1 }+\frac{ 1}{ 2n+2 }-\frac{2}{ 2n + 2} =$
$= \frac{ 1}{ 2n+1 }-\frac{ 1}{ 2n+2 } =$
$= \frac{ 1}{ 2n+1 }-\frac{ 1}{ 2n+2 } =$
$= \frac{ 2n+2-2n-1}{ (2n+1)(2n+2) } =$
$= \frac{ 2n+2-2n-1}{ (2n+1)(2n+2) } =$
$= \frac{ 1}{ (2n+1)(2n+2) } >0$
so

$x_{n+1} - x_n>0$
$x_{n+1} > x_n$

and the sequence is increasing

$\frac{ 1}{ n+1 } < \frac{1}{n}$
$\frac{ 1}{ n+2 } < \frac{1}{n}$
...
$\frac{ 1}{ 2n } < \frac{1}{n}$

we add and we have

$x_n <1$
so the sequence is bounded above