# Approximation of sum using Riemann integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}$$
We would like to approximate this sum using Riemann integral.
My approach is following:
Let $f:[n+1, 2n]\to \mathbb{R}$, $f(n)=\frac1n$. Let $P=(x_0, x_1,..., x_n)=(n+1, n+2, ..., 2n)$
Then $$\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_{i+1})(x_{i+1}-x_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_{i+1})$$
So, we have that $$\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}\to \int_{[n+1,2n]}\frac1xdx$$

I am not sure if I am ok, help me please understand these issues.

Comment: Basically you want $\int_1^2\frac1x\,dx$ with the interval $[1,2]$ split into $n$ equal length subintervals. For a related discussion of these sums see for example [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/73550/11619).

Comment: The RHS of the limit you wrote at the end of your question depends on $n$. This is a sure sign that (and in this case it happens to be due to the main reason why) something is not going well.

Comment: Why interval $[1,2]$ ?  Is it important ?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k+n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}$$