# How do I find $\sum_{i=n/2}^n{1/i}$?

Tags: summation

I was struggling to find the sum of $\sum_{i=n/2}^n{1/i}$.
I came up with a series 
$$S = \frac{2}{n} + \frac{2}{(n+2)}+\frac2{(n+4)}+\ldots+\frac{2}{2n}$$
But I am not being able to find which formula to use to find thi sum

Comment: You either write it as $H_{n} - H_{n/2-1}$ or not at all.

Comment: Is this the full problem as is delivered unto you?

Comment: There is no simple closed formula for [Harmonic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_numbers) and your expression is just a difference of two of these.

Comment: A compendium of techniques of studying the limit of these sums has been collected [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/73550/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a nice answer, but you can make a good approximation with

$$\sum_{i=n/2}^n \frac{1}{i} \approx \int_{n/2-1}^{n} \frac{1}{x} \; dx = \ln \frac{2n}{n-2}.$$

There's a little problem that $n/2$ might not be an integer, so the above assumes $n$ is even.  If $n$ is odd, change the lower integration limit to $(n-1)/2.$