# Prove that: $1-\frac 12+\frac 13-\frac 14+...+\frac {1}{199}- \frac{1}{200}=\frac{1}{101}+\frac{1}{102}+...+\frac{1}{200}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Prove that:

> $$1-\frac 12+\frac 13-\frac 14+...+\frac {1}{199}- \frac{1}{200}=\frac{1}{101}+\frac{1}{102}+...+\frac{1}{200}$$

I know only this method:

$\frac {1}{1×2}+\frac {1}{2×3}+\frac {1}{3×4}+....=1-\frac {1}{2}+\frac {1}{2}-\frac {1}{3}+\frac {1}{3}-...$

But, unfortunately, I could not a hint.

Comment: Write $-\frac{1}{2k}$ as $+\frac{1}{2k} - \frac{1}{k}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer There's (almost) nothing more to say after your comment. Why not make it an answer?

Comment: Suppose you render the R.H.S. in terms of a Riemann sum and let the number of terms go to infinity in the appropriate way on each side -- you prove that the infinite series on the left sums to $\log 2$!

Comment: See also [zyx's answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/73563/11619).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following @Daniel Fischer's comment: Write $-\frac{1}{2k}$ as $+\frac{1}{2k}-\frac{1}{k}$

> we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j=1}^{200}(-1)^{j+1}\frac{1}{j}}&=\sum_{j=1}^{100}\frac{1}{2j-1}-\sum_{j=1}^{100}\frac{1}{2j}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^{100}\frac{1}{2j-1}+\left(\sum_{j=1}^{100}\frac{1}{2j}-\sum_{j=1}^{100}\frac{1}{j}\right)\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^{200}\frac{1}{j}-\sum_{j=1}^{100}\frac{1}{j}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=101}^{200}\frac{1}{j}}
> \end{align*}

**Note:** With respect to a comment from OP a small supplement to @Zaharyas nice approach.

> We consider a smaller sum to better see what's going on. 
>   The following is valid
>   \begin{align*}
> 1-\frac{1}{2}&
> +\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{13}-\frac{1}{14}+\frac{1}{15}-\frac{1}{16}\\
> &=\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{13}+\frac{1}{14}+\frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{16}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> The main idea is to reorder the left-hand side of (1) and organise it in blocks. Each block starts with a fraction with an *odd denominator* as leader and we put all numbers within a block where the denominator is a power of two of this odd denominator.
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> 1-\frac{1}{2}&
> +\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{13}-\frac{1}{14}+\frac{1}{15}-\frac{1}{16}\\
> &=\underbrace{\left(1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{16}\right)}_{\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{16}}}
> +\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{12}\right)}_{\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{12}}}\\
> &\qquad+\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{10}\right)}_{\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{10}}}
> +\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{14}\right)}_{\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{14}}}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{13}+\frac{1}{15}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{13}+\frac{1}{14}+\frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{16}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we observe the right-hand side is organized into $8$ blocks. The first four blocks contain more than one number and four blocks which consist of one number only. We note that each natural number $a\in \mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ has a unique representation as power of two times an odd number.
  \begin{align*}
  a=b\cdot 2^k\qquad\qquad k\geq 0, b\text{ odd}
  \end{align*}
  The second block in the right-hand side of (2) for instance has the representation
  \begin{align*}
  \left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{6}-\color{blue}{\frac{1}{12}}\right)&=\left(\frac{1}{3\cdot 2^0}-\frac{1}{3\cdot2^1}-\frac{1}{3\cdot2^2}\right)
  =\frac{1}{3}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)\\
  &=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{4}
  \color{blue}{=\frac{1}{12}}
  \end{align*}
  This unique representation asserts that we take all fractions $\frac{1}{k}$ with $1\leq k\leq 16$ in the right-hand side of (2).

  Another nice  fact is that the value of each block is given by its right-most entry. This is due to the *[finite geometric series formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)*. We obtain
  \begin{align*}
  1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}-\cdots\color{blue}{-\frac{1}{2^{k}}}
  &=1-\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\right)\\
  &=1-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{1}{2^j}\\
  &=1-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1-\frac{1}{2^k}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}\\
  &\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{2^k}}
  \end{align*}
- In (3) we write for each block the corresponding fraction and reorder the numbers.

> Keeping all this in mind we can now show the original identity using sigma notation. We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j=1}^{200}(-1)^{j+1}\frac{1}{j}}&
> =\sum_{j=1}^{50}\left(\frac{1}{2j-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\log_{2}\left(\frac{200}{2j-1}\right)\right\rfloor}\frac{1}{(2j-1)\cdot 2^k}\right)
> +\sum_{j=51}^{100}\frac{1}{2j-1}\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^{50}\frac{1}{(2j-1)\cdot 2^{\left\lfloor\log_{2}\left(\frac{200}{2j-1}\right)\right\rfloor}}+\sum_{j=51}^{100}\frac{1}{2j-1}\tag{5}\\
> &=\sum_{j=51}^{100}\frac{1}{2j}+\sum_{j=51}^{100}\frac{1}{2j-1}\tag{6}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=101}^{200}\frac{1}{j}}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (4) we use the fact that we have $200$ summands, $100$ with odd denominator and $100$ with even denominator. We take the $100$ odd as leaders of $100$ blocks. Thereby we have $50$ blocks with more than one term and $50$ block with one term only. This corresponds to the representation in (2).
- In (5) we use that each block is given by the right-most term as indicated by braces in (2) and also shown in the comment-section above. We can verify the expression $(2j-1)\cdot 2^{\left\lfloor\log_{2}\left(\frac{200}{2j-1}\right)\right\rfloor}$ with *$$\text{Sort[Table[(2*j-1)*2^Floor[ld(200/(2*j-1))],{j,1,50}]]}$$* in Wolfram Alpha and get
  \begin{align*}
  102,104,106,\ldots,198,200
  \end{align*}
- In (6) we use the unique representation of even numbers as odd number times a power of two and collect them in sorted order as we did in (3).

Comment: +1) Finally, I understood your solution. But, I don't understand Zaharyas's solution..Can you explain me, please??:(

Comment: @I'mastudent: Thanks!  :-) and  yes, I can. I  will soon add a small supplement which might be helpful.

Comment: Very, very, very Thanks!! :)

Comment: @I'mastudent: Supplement added. Regards,

Comment: Endless thanks !!!  I understood :) ✓

Comment: @I'mastudent: You're welcome. Congrats! Good to see the answer is useful. :-)

Comment: I have read your new edits with pleasure. But I did not understand your last part..  "Sort", "table".

Comment: @I'mastudent: Feed *[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sort%5BTable%5B(2*j-1)*2%5EFloor%5Bld(200%2F(2*j-1))%5D,%7Bj,1,50%7D%5D%5D)* with it. Table[...,{j,1,50}] tabulates values from $j=1,\ldots,50$ and Sort[] presents these values in increasingly sorted order. The $\log_2$ is *ld* the logarithmus dualis and Floor(x) truncates to the nearest integer less or equal to $x$.

Comment: Now, I understood..,thank you again. :).

Comment: and I must say, Your sigma definition is so amazing. :)

Comment: @I'mastudent: You're too friendly. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 6):

My method :

> $$\left\{ 1-\frac {1}{2}-\frac {1}{4}-...-\frac {1}{128} \right\}+\left\{ \frac {1}{3}-\frac {1}{6}- \frac{1}{12}-...- \frac{1}{192}\right\}+\left\{\frac {1}{5}-\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{20}-...- \frac{1}{160}\right\}+...+\left\{ \frac{1}{99}-\frac{1}{198}\right\}+\left\{ \frac{1}{101}+\frac{1}{103}+\frac{1}{105}+...+\frac{1}{199}\right\}=\frac{1}{101}+\frac{1}{102}+\frac{1}{103}+...+\frac{1}{200}$$

Comment: How do you get the $\frac{1}{102}$?

Comment: $\frac{1}{51}-\frac{1}{102}=\frac{1}{102}$

Comment: Each even number is uniquely the product of an odd denomibator appearing with positive sign on the L.H.S., times a power of $2$.  This guarantees that each even denominator in the relevant range will appear exactly once on the right side once terms with like odd factors in the denominators are collected from the alternating series.

Comment: I do not understand much..

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{k= 1}^{200}(-1)^{k+1}k^{-1}=1-\frac 12+\frac 13-\frac 14+\cdots+\frac {1}{199}- \frac{1}{200}=\frac{1}{101}+\frac{1}{102}+\cdots+\frac{1}{200}=$$
$$\color{blue}{\left(1+\frac 13+\frac 15 +\dots+ \frac 1{199}\right)-\left(\frac 12+ \frac 14+\frac 16\cdots+\frac {1}{200}\right)}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{101}+\frac{1}{102}+\cdots+\frac{1}{200}}$$

> \begin{align}
> \tag1
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac{1}{2k-1} - \sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac{1}{2k}} &= \color{red}{\sum_{k=101}^{200}\frac{1}{k}}\\
> \tag2
> &= \sum_{k=1}^{200}\frac{1}{k} - \sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac{1}{k}\\
> \tag3
> &= \left(\sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac{1}{2k} + \sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac{1}{2k-1}\right) - \sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac{1}{k}\\
> \tag4
> &= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac{1}{k} + \sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac{1}{2k-1}- \sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac{1}{k}\\
> \tag5
> &= \sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac{1}{2k-1}- \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac{1}{k}\\
> \tag6
> &= \underbrace{\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac{1}{2k-1}- \sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac{1}{2k}}}\\
> &\quad\quad\quad\sum_{k= 1}^{200}(-1)^{k+1}k^{-1}\\
> &&\Box
> \end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Hint: prove by induction that $\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{i}=\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{i}$.

Answer (score 1):

We have 
\begin{split} &&1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{199} - \frac{1}{200} \\&=& 
\left(1 + \frac{1}{3} +  \frac{1}{5} +\cdots + \frac{1}{197}+\frac{1}{199}  \right) - \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{200}\right)\\
&=&
 \left(1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{199} + \frac{1}{200}\right) - 2 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{200}\right)\\
&=&\left(1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots  \frac{1}{100}\right)+\left(  \frac{1}{101}+\cdots +\frac{1}{199} + \frac{1}{200}\right) - \left(\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{100}\right)\\[10pt]
&= &\frac{1}{101} + \frac{1}{102} + \cdots + \frac{1}{200}\end{split}

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered a neat solution:

Add $ 1 + \frac{1}{2} +  \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{100} $ to both sides and it will be easy to see they are indeed equal.

Because on LHS, every negative term can be added with a positive term twice its size. Examples
$$-\frac{1}{2} + 1 = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$-\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2}= \frac{1}{4}$$
$$-\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{3}= \frac{1}{6}$$

and so on.