# Limit of the difference between two harmonic numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, harmonic-numbers

I am trying to evaluate the following limit:

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} H_{kn} - H_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i = 1}^{(k - 1)n} \frac{1}{n + 1}
$$

I know that the answer is $\ln k$, but I have no idea how to even approach this problem. I have tried somehow equating this to the Taylor expansion of $\ln(1 + (k - 1))$, but to no avail.

Comment: Here is the case $k=2$: [The limit of truncated sums of harmonic series, $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=k+1}^{2k}{\frac{1}{n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/73550)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Use the Riemann sum to evaluate

$$H_{kn}-H_n =\sum_{m=1}^{(k-1)n}\frac1{n+m}=\frac1n \sum_{m=1}^{(k-1)n}\frac{1}{1+m/n}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Use the fact that
$$\lim_{n} H_{kn}-\ln(kn)=\lim_n H_n-\ln(n)=\gamma$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the asymptotics
$$H_p=\gamma +\log \left({p}\right)+\frac{1}{2
   p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)$$ making
$$H_{kn}-H_n=\log \left({k}\right)+\frac{\frac{1}{k}-1}{2
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$