# Sequences and Series problem with alternating signs

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to prove that
$$1-\frac12+\frac13-\cdots-\frac1{200} = \frac1{101}+\frac1{102}+\cdots+\frac1{200}$$
I have tried to relate it to various expansions of Taylor Maclaurin series but to no avail. Please do not solve the problem. I need a hint.

Comment: Hint: $-\frac12 = \frac12 - 1, -\frac14 = \frac14 - \frac12, \cdots, -\frac{1}{200} = \frac{1}{200} - \frac{1}{100}$

Comment: Thanks Sir I got it

Comment: Also, see [this comment by zyx](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/73563/11619). Comes to much the same thing but in a single strike.

Comment: @achillehui: I'd call that an answer :-)