# Explanation in a step of the summation $\frac{1}{2^n+1} + \frac{1}{2^n+2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, proof-explanation

I have the solution to the above equation but I wanted to know the explanation for it.

$$\frac{1}{2^n+1} + \frac{1}{2^n+2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} = 2^n \frac{1}{  2^{n+1}}$$
and
$$2^n\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2} \qquad \text{(I understand this part)}.$$

I wasn't sure how that became the product of those 2 numbers. Any explanation please? Thank you.

To make it clearer let me include this link:
[https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~hsharp/math2420/harmonic.pdf](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/%7Ehsharp/math2420/harmonic.pdf)

Look at line 5

Im open to any alternative suggestions to solve the problem.

Comment: It seems that you only have inequality

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by that

Comment: $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ is the smalest term of your sum, and you have $2^n$ terms, so your sum is bounded by number of term multiplied by smalest term, which is what you wrote. Conversely you can show that it is bounded by above by number of term times largest one which turns up to be $1$. so your sum is between $1/2$ and $1$.

Comment: I hazard a guess that you really have [this sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/73550/11619) with $k$ there equal to your $2^n$. Anyway, there is no closed form for this sum, but as $n\to\infty$ it tends to $\ln 2$ as a limit. In other words, the "equality" of your first displayed formula is not correct.

Comment: Try $n=1$ or $n=2$ for example, the equality is not correct.

Comment: ... and there's an **in**equality in the PDF.

Comment: so the pdf is wrong?

Comment: The pdf is not wrong as it has a $\ge$ sign and not an $=$ at the start of line 5. You incorrectly changed it to an equals sign here.

Answer (score 1):

We have an inequality since $$\frac{1}{2^n+i}\geq \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$$

for $1\leq i\leq 2^{n}.$ Thus $$\sum_{i=1}^{2^{n}}\frac{1}{2^n+i}\geq\sum_{i=1}^{2^n}\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\sum_{i=1}^{2^n}1=2^n\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$$