# Limit of 1/n + ... + 1/2n

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, monotone-functions

Recently my professor gave us the exercise of proving wether the sequence a_n=1/n + 1/n+1 + ... + 1/2n was convergent.
It's not very hard to find It's monotonous and 0<=a_n<=1.5 for all n (this has a name, but I don't know how it's spelled in english), then it must converge.

So my question: what does this limit equal? Is it a unique constant difined as the limit, or is it rational, or does it have relation with some other constants?

Comment: You can work this out by using asymptotics for the [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation). It should be $\ln 2$. It should be possible to prove this directly by showing that $a_n$ approximates the integral $\int_n^{2n} \tfrac 1x \,\mathrm dx$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. The limit is $\log2$. Besides integral comparison, you can prove it by applying the convexity inequality $\log(1+x)\le x\le -{\log(1-x)}$ (valid for any $x\in(0,1)$) to $x=\frac1{n+k}$ and summing it from $k=0$ to $n$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The limit of truncated sums of harmonic series, $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=k+1}^{2k}{\frac{1}{n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73550/the-limit-of-truncated-sums-of-harmonic-series-lim-limits-k-to-infty-sum-n) Found [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3Dn%7D%5E%7B2n%7D%5Cfrac1k%24&p=1), where you can find many other duplicates.